# Cannot call custom draw method from another class in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

its my first time to ask a question here. I have this problem with my android app.
I would like to create different draw methods inside my custom view class. There are three buttons corresponding to 3 different shapes. When a button is pressed it will draw its shape. But the app crashes when I try to call the custom draw from the MainActivity for me to test it.

MainActivity

```
import com.example.shapes.view.ShapesView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ShapesView shapesview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    shapesview = (ShapesView) findViewById(R.id.ShapesViewID);
    shapesview.DrawRectangle();
}
```

ShapesView

```
public class ShapesView extends View{

Canvas canvas;

public ShapesView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.canvas = canvas;
}

public void DrawRectangle() {
    Paint mypaint = new Paint();
    mypaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 200, 200, mypaint);
}
}
```

My XML layout file

`<com.example.shapes.view.ShapesView 
        android:id="@+id/ShapesViewID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />`

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`
```

Please do help! Thank you very much!

Comment: Do not store a reference to canvas. Always use the one provided in "onDraw()". If you want to draw whenever you want, consider using a `TextureView`.

Comment: Oh okay. Ill check that out! But why cant I do that? The code works if I'd comment out shapesview.DrawRectangle(); and add DrawRectangle inside onDraw(); Thanks!

Comment: The framework gives possibility to draw contents of your view in onDraw method. Framework can't effectively say, that you have done with graphics output and on other side it can't afford redraw compontent after each call to `draw*()` methods. So, you can try to call `invalidate` as proposed Chintan Rathod. But I can't guarantee that it will work.

Comment: crash => post stacktrace.

Comment: The on draw method of your custom view has not called by the system yet when your activity creates itself and therefore the canvas will be null. The first comment points to the right direction...

Comment: for FSM sake ... **you can not use canvas from `onDraw` outside `onDraw`** ... put code from `DrawRectangle` into `onDraw` and in activity call `shapesView.invalidate()` in your Activity

Comment: But the XML automatically runs onDraw right? Because I tried code on comment 2 and it worked. BTW I got the idea from this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952601/ondraw-for-view)

Comment: Yes but not during activity onCreate it calls it much later, I think in onAttachedToWindow or something...

Comment: @slashred Reason updated in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question you need a custom view (a button) which will draw itself differently based on some event. If that is the case then you need to respect the android's guidelines about the view drawing take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html).

Now one possible solution for your case is to set some kind of flag about the state of your view and then use that flag when you are ready to draw. For example you can do this:

```
public class ShapesView extends View{

public int state = 0;

public ShapesView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onDraw(canvas);
if (state == 1) {
    Paint mypaint = new Paint();
    mypaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 200, 200, mypaint);
}
}
```

and then whenever you need to draw your view from an activity you can use the following:

```
myview.state = 1;
myview.invalidate();
```

In your code what you are doing is that you call a views function during the onCreate of your activity which in turn tries to use a null canvas because the onDraw method of your view has not be called during that time. Furthermore as others have pointed out you must not use a canvas object outside the onDraw method.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes! It worked and  I can just use switch with state as parameter so I could control which shape to draw. But I have one more problem. I added this code `public void setColorGreen() {
  mypaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  invalidate(); }` 
in the CustomView Class and tried to run it in mainactivity using `shapesview.setColorGreen();` The app crashed, why is that so? Is mypaint already recycled after onDraw?

Comment: And yes it does. I created another instance of mypaint inside setColorGreen. Thank you very much sir! Do you think having switch inside onDraw to control which shape to draw is a good practice? I would actually use this same logic in a guitar chord viewer application. So that when the user chooses chord a then it will show a. But there are too many thus making onDraw cluttered.

Comment: Yes it is as long as you keep the onDraw method as small and as quick as possible. Keep in mind that the onDraw method can be called many many times by the system. For example you have 20 views on a layout, the onDraw will be called at least 20 times for those to render...

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code with following.

```
public class ShapesView extends View {

    Paint mypaint;

    public ShapesView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mypaint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mypaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 200, 200, mypaint);
    }
}
```

When you want to draw, call `shapesview.invalidate();`

Comment: But I have to separate different draw methods from onDraw which I will be controlled from onclicklisteners on MainActivity. But thank you so much for the effort sir!

Answer (score 1):

Look at method's name its `onDraw()` and not `getCanvas()`. The documentation also doesn't makes any claims about the `Canvas` provided.

After `onDraw()` is done, that `canvas` may be disposed, its bitmap/buffer may be re-cycled, who knows.

So, it is not safe to use the Canvas outside of this method. Draw what you want, but only inside `onDraw()` method.

If you want to trigger the View to re-draw, at some other time, call `invalidate()`.

#### Example:

View class to render any shape:

```
public class ShapeView extends View {

    private Paint mPaint;
    private ShapeRenderer mRenderer;

    public ShapeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ShapeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ShapeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        mPaint = new Paint();
    }

    public void setPaintColor(int color){
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public void setPaintStrokeWidth(float width){
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(width);
    }

    public void setRenderer(ShapeRenderer renderer) {
        mRenderer = renderer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if(mRenderer != null){
            mRenderer.drawShape(canvas,mPaint);
        }
    }

    public static interface ShapeRenderer{
        public void drawShape(Canvas canvas, Paint paint);
    }
}
```

A Class that draws a rectangle:

```
public class RectRenderer implements ShapeView.ShapeRenderer {
    @Override
    public void drawShape(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
        canvas.drawRect(0,0,100,100,paint);
    }
}
```

Draw a shape at runtime:

```
 myShapeView.setPaintColor(Color.GREEN);
 myShapeView.setPaintStroke(5f);
 myShapeView.setRenderer(new RectRenderer());
 myShapeView.invalidate();
```

Comment: I think this is the most convenient solution.

Comment: Okay! I understood sir. But one more question please. I dont know if this will be off topic. I added another method inside ShapesView class. And it's 
`setColorGreen() {
mypaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
 }`
I edited the code for Paint also. But when I try to access setColorGreen from MainActivity the app still crashes. Maybe theres something wrong on how I referenced it?

Comment: @S.D. Do you think this piece of code does the right thing? Does it really reference it `shapesview = (ShapesView) findViewById(R.id.ShapesViewID);` Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must redesign your component, so it can draw itself in onDraw method. If you need some class that must contain Canvas, you can try to do something like this.

```
class Drawer {
  private Canvas canvas;

  public Drawer(Canvas canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
  }

  public void DrawRectangle() {
    Paint mypaint = new Paint();
    mypaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 200, 200, mypaint);
  }
}
```

On yours custom view you can do something like this.

```
public class ShapesView extends View{

  public ShapesView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Drawer drawer = new Drawer(canvas);
    drawer.DrawRectangle();
  }

  public void DrawRectangle() {
    Paint mypaint = new Paint();
    mypaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 200, 200, mypaint);
  }
}
```